# Spark - failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException - localhost

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am running hadoop and spark in a single machine (Ubuntu 14.04). JPS command gives me below output

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ jps
4370 HRegionServer
6568 Jps
5555 RunJar
3744 TaskTracker
5341 RunJar
4120 HQuorumPeer
5790 SparkSubmit
3308 DataNode
4203 HMaster
3469 SecondaryNameNode
3079 NameNode
3587 JobTracker
```

I have created a file simple csv in HDFS. The below details of the file.

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser/file_for_spark/spark1.csv
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup        174 2015-04-16 08:14 /user/hduser/file_for_spark/spark1.csv
```

But while trying to access the file from spark I am getting the failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused error

```
          ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.3.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_21)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Spark context available as sc.
SQL context available as sqlContext.

scala> val pagecount=sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:3079/user/hduser/file_for_spark/spark1.csv")
pagecount: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = hdfs://localhost:3079/user/hduser/file_for_spark/spark1.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:21

scala> pagecount.count()
java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:3079 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1099)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1075)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1511)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1006)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:29)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:31)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:33)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:35)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:37)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
    at <init>(<console>:43)
    at .<init>(<console>:47)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:856)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:813)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:664)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:669)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1058)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:434)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2000(Client.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1050)
    ... 73 more
```

**EDIT 1 :**

@Paul
The command gives the below output

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ lsof -p 3079 -a -i
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    3079 hduser   65u  IPv4  17260      0t0  TCP *:33736 (LISTEN)
java    3079 hduser   75u  IPv4  17341      0t0  TCP localhost:54310 (LISTEN)
java    3079 hduser   85u  IPv4  22609      0t0  TCP *:50070 (LISTEN)
java    3079 hduser   89u  IPv4  59998      0t0  TCP localhost:54310->localhost:46507 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Could you please let me know what's exactly happening in port 46507

Comment: You are trying to connect to hdfs with a user that doesn't have permissions on HDFS

Comment: I know that you have already answered your question but code snippets are to use with just with JavaScript, CSS, and HTML, first and comment are not to give as answer! you can edit your question if you wish to add informations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry... actually namenode is running in a different port which I found from core-site.xml. It works for me after using the port 54310.

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Could someone please tell me what does 3079 means here, which is the output of JPS command.

Comment: the output of `jps` with no flags is the list of your java process ids. Try using `jps --help`for all available options

Answer (score 0):

That's a good answer to yourself ! :)

3079 is the pid ( process id ) of namenode. See more details about jps's output here: [Jps doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html). BTW, you can verify the listening ports of namenode using the pid with a command such as:

```
lsof -p 3079 -a -i
```

In your command output:

```
java    3079 hduser   89u  IPv4  59998      0t0  TCP localhost:54310->localhost:46507 (ESTABLISHED)
```

That line indicates that other process established TCP connection with Namenode at port 46507. Possible processes could be resoure manager(RM) or data nodes etc.