# spark scala on windows machine

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am learning from the [class](https://www.udemy.com/big-data-analytics-with-apache-spark-and-scala/learn/v4/t/lecture/4729300). I have run the code as shown in the class and i get below errors. Any idea what i should do?

I have spark 1.6.1 and Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_74)

```
val datadir = "C:/Personal/V2Maestros/Courses/Big Data Analytics with Spark/Scala"

//............................................................................
////   Building and saving the model
//............................................................................

val tweetData = sc.textFile(datadir + "/movietweets.csv")
tweetData.collect()

def convertToRDD(inStr : String) : (Double,String) = {
    val attList = inStr.split(",")
    val sentiment = attList(0).contains("positive") match {
            case  true => 0.0
            case  false    => 1.0
     }
    return (sentiment, attList(1))
}
val tweetText=tweetData.map(convertToRDD)
tweetText.collect()

//val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
var ttDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(tweetText).toDF("label","text")
ttDF.show()
```

The error is:

```
scala> ttDF.show()
[Stage 2:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 2]16/03/30 11:40:25 ERROR ExecutorClassLoader: Failed to check existence of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressio
REPL class server at http://192.168.56.1:54595
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
       re/4729300
```

Comment: Can you show the line where you create the SparkContext, `sc`?

Comment: i use the default one..

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but the connection IP in the error message looks like a private node or even your router/modem local address.

As stated in the comment it could be that you're running the context with a wrong configuration that tries to spread the work to a cluster that's not there, instead of in your local jvm process.

For further information you can read [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#using-the-shell) and experiment with something like

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

val sc = new SparkContext(master = "local[4]", appName = "tweetsClass", conf = new SparkConf)
```

---

#### Update

Since you're using the interactive shell and the provided `SparkContext` available there, I guess you should pass the equivalent parameters to the shell command as in

```
<your-spark-path>/bin/spark-shell --master local[4]
```

Which instructs the driver to assign a master for the spark cluster on the local machine, on 4 threads.

Comment: but when i run similar code in python it runs fine. That being said I will run the code that you have suggested

Comment: please give me the correct command. I get errors when i run your comand `scala> new SparkContext(master = "local[4]", appName = "tweetsClass", conf = new SparkConf)
<console>:26: error: not found: type SparkContext
              new SparkContext(master = "local[4]", appName = "tweetsClass", conf = new SparkConf)
                  ^

scala> val sc = new SparkContext(master = "local[4]", appName = "tweetsClass", conf = new SparkConf)
<console>:25: error: not found: type SparkContext
         `

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes with connectivity and not from within the code.

Check if you can actually connect to this address and port (54595).

Comment: i didnt get you. all the data is on my pc. The command `tweetText.collect()` runs fine

Comment: That's irrelevant @user2543622. I mean that you cannot connect to that address:port! Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679951/spark-failed-on-connection-exception-java-net-connectexception-localhost

Comment: i looked at your link. But not sure how to fix my problem. any inputs?

Comment: i also noticed that the port changes every time i run the code :(

Comment: @user2543622 I got nothing in mind now, good luck. I will upvote your question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your spark master is not accessible at the specified port. Use local[*] to validate using a smaller dataset and local master. Then, ckeck if the port is accessible or change it based on Spark port configuration (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)